# Можно ли это назвать обособленными обстоятельствами времени?

Tags: пунктуация

Каким бы Вы хотели его видеть на следующий юбилей (,) через 5 лет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, это уточняющий оборот. На следующий юбилей (когда именно?), через 5 лет. Могу, конечно, ошибаться.

Comment: Да, я тоже почти уверена, что нужна запятая или тире. Спасибо.